# PHP pass variables to system('zipcloak')

Tags: php, ubuntu, system, php-ziparchive

I have a task, the customer wants us to encrypt his zip files with a password. I use `ZipArchive` in php to generate the zip files, but the server runs php 5.5 and my boss doesn't want to upgrade yet. The customer needs the encrypted zip files and we can't postpone this anymore... The `ZipArchive::setPassword()` works only above 5.6. I'm trying to bypass it by calling `system('zipcloak asd.zip');`When I run it from terminal, it asks for the password. I'm curious if I can pass the user given password to the command as a variable or I need a better workaround for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look into `proc_open()` that allows for control over stdin, etc.

Comment: Or, you could try `system('echo "password" | zipcloak asd.zip')` :)